# JSDOM scraping on cloudfoundry doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud-foundry, jsdom

I'm using the jsdom node.js module for an app that does some web scraping to get some data it needs.  This works perfectly fine when I run locally.

When I push the application to cloudfoundry however, it crashes.  The log is as follows:

> ====> /logs/stderr.log <====
>
> /var/vcap/data/dea/apps/caretogethersandbox-0-8b20af9255bbf552d0f490cb60d0df55/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:171
>       features   = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(window.document.implementation._fea
>                                                             ^TypeError: Cannot read property 'implementation' of undefined

Is there something I'm missing here?  I'm pretty stumped.  I know the code I've written works fine, it just seems to be an issue between the module and cloudfoundry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this problem pretty easily. It seems jsdom relies on a native compiled library called Contextify (https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify) and also has some bindings to Python from what I can gather. These are not supported by Cloud Foundry at present. There is a similar question on Github about this problem;

https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/436

The last post at the time of writing this suggests the use of two 100% JS libraries called Domino and Zepto Node, they may well be worth checking out.

Comment: I am truly touched you took the time to reproduce my problem.  This was the way to go.  I also couldn't help but notice we work for the same company ;)

Comment: Ah! nice, turns out that node.js package also has some crazy dependency on Python too! Which is actually why it doesn't work!

Comment: Python dependency, WTF? If more of reason to ditch jsdom for cheerio.

Comment: @jamjam I liked the cheerio module a lot, it was REALLY fast doing what I needed it to.  Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to run on cloudfoundry either :(  which is  shame as I'm struggling with memory usage with the Domino Zepto modules

Answer (score 1):

With only what you posted to go by its pretty much impossible to give you a direct answer.

But I have a couple of suggestions.

1. You have environmental variables that don't work the same in production as they do in development.
2. jsdom relies on jquery that is normally loaded-in externally. 
   Perhaps jquery is not loading properly.

Have you heard of [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio). Its an alternative to jsdom that implements a subset of jquery and does not need to load jquery in externally. This makes much faster than jsdom.

You can watch this [video](https://vimeo.com/31950192) created by the author for introduction to cheerio and learn more of its benefits.

Use the sample code on the [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) github page and upload it your cloudfoundry account to see if everything works. Then you can make decision on weather to switch to cheerio.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the vague post, it's just that this is the only info I have to go on.  I'm pretty sure posting the code will only distract from what's really the problem.  I'll give this a try when I'm back at my main computer.