# JSDom Alternative with full Sizzle support?

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry, sizzle, jsdom, appfog

For a bit of scope, I have a scraping app that I am running on cloudfoundry. Due to the Contextify problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083190/jsdom-scraping-on-cloudfoundry-doesnt-work), I am unable to use jsdom to do this.

To get around this problem I started to replace jsdom with [Cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio), however I have now realised it does not fully support the Sizzle selectors I need to use to process the scraped data.

After a little research I'm beginning to think I've hit a brick wall - is there another way around this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for the delay on this. You can now successfully install JSDOM on Cloudfoundry, however, it seems some functionality is unavailable. Creating a browser window, to use jQuery for example, is not possible. However, you can create a jsdom document.

Given the following example;

```
  var http = require('http');
  var util = require('util');
  var jsdom = require("jsdom");

  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    res.write("JSDom object;");
    createDocAndQuery(res);

    res.write("\nNumber of node.js releases = ");
    getLinkCount(res);

  }).listen(3000);

  function createDocAndQuery(response) {
    var doc = jsdom.jsdom("<html><body></body></html>", jsdom.level(1, "core"));
    response.write(util.inspect(doc));
  }

  function getLinkCount(response) {
    jsdom.env(
      "http://nodejs.org/dist/",
      ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
      function (errors, window) {
        response.end ("" + window.$("a").length)
      }
    );
  }
```

The first part of this works on CloudFoundry.com, the second part fails however, when creating a window object.